# what are the chmod rights recommended to give for every folders of wordpress projects

Tags: server, deployment

When deploying a wordpress project on a server , what are the rights to set for each folders and files of wordpress for it to be safe and fonctionnal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#File_Permissions

> `/` - The root WordPress directory: all files should be writable only by your user account, except .htaccess if you want WordPress to automatically generate rewrite rules for you.
>
> `/wp-admin/` - The WordPress administration area: all files should be writable only by your user account.
>
> `/wp-includes/` - The bulk of WordPress application logic: all files should be writable only by your user account.
>
> `/wp-content/` - User-supplied content: intended to be writable by your user account and the web server process.
>
> Within /wp-content/ you will find:
>
> `/wp-content/themes/` - Theme files. If you want to use the built-in theme editor, all files need to be writable by the web server process. If you do not want to use the built-in theme editor, all files can be writable only by your user account.
>
> `/wp-content/plugins/` - Plugin files: all files should be writable only by your user account.
>
> Other directories that may be present with /wp-content/ should be documented by whichever plugin or theme requires them. Permissions may vary.